# Error: Failed Building Wheel For Dm-tree Failed To Build Dm-tree Error: Could Not Build Wheels for Dm-tree, which Is Required To Install Pyproject

Tags: python, keras, pip

Error:failed Building Wheel For Dm-tree Failed To Build Dm-tree Error:could Not Build Wheelsfor Dm-tree, Ehich Is Required To Install Pyproject.toml-based Projects

Faced this error when trying to install keras

I am expecting a solution to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to `python 3.12`

`Keras` and `Tensorflow` both are not supported yet for `python 3.12`

You need to install `python 3.11` until they are supported.